# Proof of equality of sets

Tags: proof-writing, field-theory

For field $F$ whose charateristic is not 2
(Definition of field characteristic: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FieldCharacteristic.html), 
$\{(a+b, a-b)|a,b \in F\} = \{(a, b)|a,b \in F\}$ ?

It seems true intuitively, but how can I prove ?
And is it false when F's characteristic is not 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ a = 2^{-1} (a+b) + 2^{-1} (a-b) $$

$$ b = 2^{-1} (a+b) - 2^{-1} (a-b) $$

Pair $(1,0)$ creates problems in characteristic $2$, as there are no two elements $x$ and $y$ such that:
$$ 1 = x+y \; \; \mathrm{and} \;\; 0 = x-y.$$

Comment: Could you show how to prove $(x,y) \in \{(a+b, a-b)|a,b \in F\} \Leftrightarrow (x,y) \in \{(a, b)|a,b \in F\}$ ? I'm not sure (a+b, a-b) covers all pairs. (a, a+1) does not cover all pairs apparently but how about (a+b, a-b) ?

Comment: I have shown that every pair $(a,b)$ can be written as $(x+y,x−y) $ for some $x$ and $y$, hence it belongs to the first set. The other inclusion is clearly true as an element the first set belongs to the second set (due to the field axioms).

Comment: And you are right that none of pairs $(a,a+1)$ belong to the first set either, in characteristic 2.The set equality fails when characteristic is 2 (you have typo in your second question).